# Can I use my Phandelver character for this weekend's League adventure without a logsheet?

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-adventurers-league

I played in the starter set with my GM but he didn't make us fill out chronicle sheets.  I want to play in a 5th level adventure this weekend but I don't have a 5th level character. Can I use my existing character?

Quote from the D&D ADVENTURERS LEAGUE PLAYER’S GUIDE 3.0 Page 8:

> D&D Adventurers League play has been developed to
>   promote in-person, public play with the D&D tabletop
>   roleplaying game. Some opportunities exist for players
>   participating at home or privately online to get involved in
>   the D&D Adventurers League. You can:
>
> - Purchase and play Lost Mine of Phandelver
> - Purchase and play the storyline season’s adventure product
>     (for example, Out of the Abyss)
>
> Simply record your play using an adventure logsheet as you
>   would any other public game. Your experience and rewards
>   earned are valid for public D&D Adventurers League play.

I can think of two ways that might work:

1. Bring the Starter Set cleric and play him as 5th level via the character sheet with the magic items he got (the Spider Staff) and go from there.
2. Treat it like I only got to 4th level with the character, respec him as a slightly different cleric that I want to play, have a GM sign off on his first official session, and move on from there. Then use the free level 4 to level 5 level up option.

Are either of these league-legal without an adventure log sheet? Can I just get a GM to sign off on them the first time I play? Am I right that I can keep the Spider Staff in either case?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm an Adventurers League Local Coordinator!

1. Get your own DCI number by going to [accounts.wizards.com](http://accounts.wizards.com) and registering. It takes 5 minutes. Your home GM is not required to have a DCI number, but you will need one for public play, so go ahead and sign up for one if you don't have one.
2. Create a logsheet for your character. Focus on the dates of each sessions, the XP gained, magic item gain, downtime, etc. Having an accurate logsheet is the primary goal, do your best to figure it out. Put your GM's name on every session, if he has a DCI number, put that too.  [Here is a logsheet tutorial.](http://dndadventurersleague.org/tutorial-for-dd-adventure-league-logsheets/)
3. Bring your 5th level character and your logsheet to your public play event. Present it to the DM for inspection. You can explain your circumstances if they have questions. As long as the character build is legal and all of your sessions are legally documented per the [AL guidelines](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/events/adventurers-league-resources), your character will be playable.

Comment: Sure follow up question, Renown I have no documentation for that what do I do for that?

Comment: Also I have a DCI number from playtesting and living greyhawk and stuff they normally just look it up for my at events but I don't remember it, maybe I need to dig up an old character.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.se! It's good to see official support answering questions here. You might take a look at the [tour]; it's a useful introduction to the site, as we're a bit different than most forums. I added the link to the AL resources, and you've earned enough [reputation](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) from this answer that you can put more links in your posts now. Again, welcome and thanks for helping!

Comment: @James Was your character part of one of the Five Factions before? (If not, you won't have any renown anyway.)

Comment: We didn't really do factions in the starter so no, that makes it easy.

Comment: DCI number found from 2009 gencon argument with WOTC over not getting credit for modules I judged, so yeah.

Comment: Alright final follow up question how much downtime would I have? Or do I need someone to look at the module to see how many breaks there are?

Answer (score 9):

Like TheSheDM, I'm an AL Local Coordinator as well.  Here are some answers to your questions.

- To start playing AL, you need to create a character at level 1.  You can't scale an existing character or a pregen to a higher level.  Unfortunately, your Lost Mine of Phandelver character with the spider staff wouldn't count as AL-legal since it wasn't played under AL guidelines (DM didn't run as AL, other players didn't log, etc.)  The good news is that characters can progress from 1st to 4th level pretty quickly, then use the "catching up" rule to advance to 5th level--as you mentioned in your original question.  If you've got the time, you and your group could feasibly create AL-legal PCs, play a few modules (either replay LMoP, play one of the other published modules, or play some D&D Expeditions in-store), and level up/catch up in time to play the Tier 2 adventure this weekend.  Otherwise, is the event offering any Tier 1 adventures?  You could create an AL-legal PC and play that, then play other Tier 2 offerings when you get to that point.
- Downtime is awarded at the end of each part of Lost Mine of Phandelver.  You get 10 downtime days for each part you complete.  So if you completed the whole adventure, your character would have 40 downtime days.
- You can play the adventure AL-legal if the DM and other players are playing so as well. In other words, a game in which only one player is playing under AL-guidelines would not be AL-legal. This is because despite that one player playing within AL-guidelines, 1) the DM might have changed things about the adventure (different encounters, different treasure, etc.) and 2) the other players might not be playing AL-legal PCs (stats may not be in-line, and some race/class builds are restricted, such as aarakocra from the Elemental Evil Player's Companion or the death domain cleric from the DMG).  However, if your DM ran the adventure by the book (no details changed) and you and the other players created your characters within AL-guidelines--point buy/standard array ability scores, average HP per level, equipment assigned by class/background, no custom background class features, etc.--you could retroactively fill in log sheets for your adventure.

Comment: @nitsua60 Thanks for the recommendation.  I added in the points I thought would be useful for others looking fort he answer.  Let me know if you feel I should edit more of my comments in.

Answer (score 2):

As of Adventurers League Season 8 (began August 2018), your character is likely not Adventurers League-legal if you haven't intentionally been playing under AL rules. For example:

- If you used XP rather than AL's Advancement Checkpoint system to
  advance in level, or
- If you kept the magic items found in your adventures rather than
  using AL's system of unlocking magic items and purchasing them with
  Treasure Checkpoints, or
- If you kept gold and mundane treasure/equipment found in your
  adventures rather than using AL's system of fixed GP rewards per
  level gained

...then your character is not AL-legal.

See the article ["Changes to D&D Adventurers League Rewards"](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/news/changes-dd-adventurers-league-rewards) for more information on the Season 8 changes.

Answer (score -3):

No. Without a log sheet, you can't use the character in League play.

Comment: Like I asked can GM help me fill out the log sheets from my notes, or sign off.  I am looking for some option to play this weekend.

Comment: Welcome to the site Ozzie. Take the [tour] as it's a useful introduction. Can you expand on your answer a bit more. Maybe provide a quote from an official Adventurer's League source and/or provide some of your own personal experience with trying this. At the moment this is an entirely unsubstantiated claim with nothing backing it up so we have no way of knowing it this is true.

Comment: This might be a technically accurate answer, but it's not a great answer yet. It could be a great answer if it continued with “but what you *can* do is…” kind of information.

Comment: I talked to my GM and the reason he gave for not recording the adventure is that he didn't want to mess with DCI numbers and log sheets.  I been mostly playing pathfinder and they have ways to validate home adventures but I couldn't find anything for here without the GM doing something.  I have no idea what renown should be but I did keep track of xp and gold and items.

Comment: Can the GM go back through and fill out chronicles for the break points in the module?

Comment: I did the best I could with the information given to me by the poster. I have no idea if the DM played according to AL rules or not (not rolling for stats, HP, gold, treasure, etc), so I have no way of knowing if his character is remotely legal or not. If the DM wasn't using logsheets, then it probably isn't, so "no, you can't use that character" is the best possible answer with that data.